# Bypass runtime type erasure for generic map serializer

Tags: java, jackson, jackson2, jackson-databind

I'm working on a serializer for a `Map<K,V>` which serializes map entries as JSON array of objects with `key` and `value` being able to contain arbitrary types (including complex types for keys). I have

```
public class MapEntryDeserializer<K,V> extends StdDeserializer<Map<K,V>> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MapEntryDeserializer(Class<Map<K,V>> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    public MapEntryDeserializer(JavaType valueType) {
        super(valueType);
    }

    @Override
    public Map<K, V> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        Map<K,V> retValue = new HashMap<>();
        List<Entry<K,V>> entries = p.readValueAs(new TypeReference<List<Entry<K,V>>>() {});
        for(Entry<K,V> entry : entries) {
            retValue.put(entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue());
        }
        return retValue;
    }

    private static class Entry<K,V> {
        private K key;
        private V value;

        public Entry() {
        }

        public K getKey() {
            return key;
        }

        public void setKey(K key) {
            this.key = key;
        }

        public V getValue() {
            return value;
        }

        public void setValue(V value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

which is working except for the `new TypeReference<List<Entry<K,V>>>` which resolves to `List<Entry<Object, Object>>` at runtime and thus nested `Entity2`s to be deserialized as `Map`.

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "valueMap" : [ {
    "key" : {
      "type" : "richtercloud.jackson.map.custom.serializer.Entity2",
      "id" : 2
    },
    "value" : 10
  } ]
}
```

So, I'm wondering whether there's a way to achieve a generic solution, e.g. pass `Class<? extends K>` and `Class<? extends V>` and construct a `JavaType` with `TypeFactory.constructParametricType`.

I'm using Jackson 2.9.4.

Comment: I'm sure this would be solved by providing `JsonParser.readAsValue(ResolvedType)` which seems to be easy to acchieve and which I suggested at https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1966.

Comment: I asked for clarification, but afaiu according to https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1967 certain serialization use case don't work at all for a long time and thus failures might occur for reasons unrelated to the actual reason that therer's no support which can cause huge time wasting.