# Deserialize Map key as POJO reference

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

Is it possible in Jackson to get a reference to a previously-deserialized object from the same json string given it's id?

For example, I have the following Java classes:

```java
public class Company {
    List<Employee> employeeList;
    List<Customer> customerList;
    ....
}

@JsonIdentityInfo(
        generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class Customer {
    Long id;
    ...
}

public class Employee {
    Long id;
    Map<Customer, int> utilityMap;
    ...
}
```

I want to create a Company instance from a json string that looks like:

```
{
  "customerList" : [ {
    "id" : 0,
    "name" : "customer0"
  } ],
  "employeeList" : [ {
    "id" : 1,
    "fullName" : "employee0",
    "utilityMap" : {
      "0" : 1
    }
  } ]
}
```

where the key 0 in utilityMap refers to the customer with id 0.

With KeyDeserializer I'm able to create a new Customer object, but I want the Map's key to be a reference to the corresponding object instead.

A simple solution would be to change the signature of `Map<Customer, int>` to be `Map<Long, int>`, but this not possible due to internal dependencies, is there another way to accomplish this without changing the model (similar to xml references)?

Comment: There isn't a standard for references in JSON, but there are a number of proposals. I have not (so far) noticed that Jackson implements any of them. I found the question [Standard way of referencing an object by identity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4001474/17300) useful, and have used the `"$ref" : #/some/path` syntax for an internal API myself, but with no help from Jackson for it.

Comment: could this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49211176/how-to-customly-serialize-or-convert-a-map-property-with-custom-key-type-in-jack help?

Comment: Thanks @thunderhook and @stephen-p! The first approach in @Jose_Da_Silva's answer is what I already have, but what I needed is exactly the reference_by_id that @stephen-p mentioned. Similar to how it's done in xml `<entry><Customer reference="1" /><value>1</value></entry>`

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76448516/jackson-deserialize-a-mapmytype-string-which-uses-jsonidentityinfo-on-mytyp

Comment: Upstream issue to vote for to avoid the need for custom deserializers: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/3984