# Jackson: deserialize a Map<MyType, String> which uses @JsonIdentityInfo on MyType

Tags: java, jackson

How do I deserialize a `Map` with a `MyType` key that uses only the id of `MyType` in the json format?

For example, given

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "id")
public class MyType {

   String id;
   ... // Getters and setters for id

   String longText;
}

public class MyData {

   List<MyType> types;

   @JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true) // Does not work
   Map<MyType, Integer> countMap;
}
```

it properly serializes `MyData` in:

```
{
  "types": [
    {
      "id": "123",
      "longText": "very long text 1 ..."
    },
    {
      "id": "456",
      "longText": "very long text 2 ..."
    }
  ],
  "countMap": {
    "123": 100,
    "456": 200
  }
}
```

But when I deserialize that, I get an error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot find a (Map) Key deserializer for type [simple type, class MyType]
```

How do I get Jackson to deserialize it correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't your `countMap` key be a `String` type?

Comment: No, after deserialization, I need the key to be of type `MyType`.

Comment: Duplicates https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54187982/deserialize-map-key-as-pojo-reference

Comment: Created an issue in Jackson: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/issues/231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using references you provided in your comment it is possible to deserialize the provided json with a class extending the [KeyDeserializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.14/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/KeyDeserializer.html) class. Starting from a simplified version of classes you defined in the question like below:

```
@Data
public class MyType {
    String id;
    String longText;
}

@Data
public class MyData {

    private List<MyType> types;

    //added annotation to the original class
    @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = MyKeyDeserializer.class)
    private Map<MyType, Integer> countMap;
}
```

With the assumption that *types* field is always present you can create a custom class extending the `KeyDeserializer`:

```
public class MyKeyDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {

    @Override
    public MyType deserializeKey(String id, DeserializationContext dc) throws IOException {
        
        MyType myType = new MyType();
        myType.setId(id);
        MyData myData = (MyData) dc.getParser()
                                .getParsingContext()
                                .getParent()
                                .getCurrentValue();
        
        MyType elem = myData.getTypes()
                                .stream()
                                .filter(el -> el.id.equals(id))
                                .findFirst()
                                .orElse(null);
        
        if (elem != null) { myType.setLongText(elem.getLongText()); }
        return myType;
    }

}
```

Basically in the code for every key of your `CountMap` map the json will be parsed to a `MyData` instance and then the *types* element will be searched to extract the type element with the same *id* returning the new *MyType* key completed with the *longText* field.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I was able to deserialize was using a custom deserializer.
So having the class

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
    property = "id")
@JsonIdentityReference(alwaysAsId = true)
public class MyType {

  String id;
  String longText;

  public MyType() {
  }

  public MyType(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
//getter&setters
}
```

and

```
public class MyData {

  List<MyType> types;
  // Does not work
  @JsonDeserialize(keyUsing = MyTypeDeserializer.class)
  Map<MyType, Integer> countMap;
//getters&setters
}

public class MyTypeDeserializer extends KeyDeserializer {
  @Override
  public Object deserializeKey(String key, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
    return new MyType(key);
  }
}
```

Running the test below I was able to see the json properly deserialized.

```
@Test
  public void testDeserialize() throws IOException {
    final String testData = "{\n" +
        "  \"types\": [\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"id\": \"123\",\n" +
        "      \"longText\": \"very long text 1 ...\"\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      \"id\": \"456\",\n" +
        "      \"longText\": \"very long text 2 ...\"\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  ],\n" +
        "  \"countMap\": {\n" +
        "    \"123\": 100,\n" +
        "    \"456\": 200\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}\n";
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    MyData myData = mapper.readValue(testData, MyData.class);
  }
```